# how does the differential equation for a series RC circuit behave?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor

I am analyzing a simple series RC circuit. I have the equation that describes the current set up but I don’t understand it. In the picture below, wouldn’t the di/dt term be 0 instantly because of the DC voltage source? Also, isn’t the current flowing in this circuit going to be 0 because of the capacitor?

[image]

Comment: i and di/dt will be zero after a prolonged period but, not when the voltage source is initially applied.

Answer (score 3):

It's a lot easier to work through if you re-arrange the series components so that the capacitor is "grounded" and the resistor is tied to the supply. (I'm assuming that at \$t=0\$ the initial voltage across the capacitor is assumed to be zero.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMJ5dD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You are allowed to re-arrange things like this. There's no conceptual change here. Just the reference is changed. But this makes the voltage across the capacitor easier to visualize.

It should be clear from this that \$I_{R_1}=\frac{V-V_{_\text{C}}}{R_1}\$ (a positive magnitude starting at \$t=0\$) and that this must be equal to the current into the capacitor, by KCL. So it follows that:

$$\frac{V_{_\text{C}}}{R_1}+C\frac{\text{d}V_{_\text{C}}}{\text{d}t}=\frac{V}{R_1}$$

Or,

$$\frac{\text{d}V_{_\text{C}}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{1}{R_1\:C_1}V_{_\text{C}}=\frac{V}{R_1\:C_1}$$

And this fits the bog-standard 1st order linear ODE form.

$$\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}t} + P_t\cdot y = Q_t$$

where \$\tau=R_1\:C_1\$, \$P_t=\frac{1}{\tau}\$, and \$Q_t=\frac{V}{\tau}\$.

The integrating factor is then:

$$\mu=e^{^{\int P_t\; \textrm{d}t}}=e^{^{\frac{t}{\tau}}}$$

And the solution is:

$$\begin{align*} y=V_{_\text{C}}&=\frac{1}{\mu}\int \mu\cdot Q_t\;\; \textrm{d}t\\\\&=e^{^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}}\int e^{^{\frac{t}{\tau}}}\cdot \frac{V}{\tau}\;\; \textrm{d}t\\\\&=\frac{V}{\tau}\cdot e^{^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}}\int e^{^{\frac{t}{\tau}}}\;\; \textrm{d}t\\\\&=V\cdot e^{^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}}\left[e^{^{\frac{t}{\tau}}}+C\right]
\end{align*}$$

At \$t=0\$ it must be the case that \$C=-1\$, given that \$V_{_\text{C}}=0\$ at \$t=0\$. So the final equation is:

$$V_{_\text{C}{\left(t\right)}}=V\left(1-e^{^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}}\right)=V\left(1-e^{^{\frac{-t}{R_1\:C_1}}}\right)$$

You can now return the circuit to its original situation, if you like. But the result will be the same for the voltage across the capacitor. And, of course, knowing that value you can also work out the instantaneous current in the resistor, as well.

Answer (score 0):

When 9V dc is applied to the left hand side of the capacitor in a theoretically instantly rising step, the right hand side of the capacitor must follow it and instantly also become 9V. The voltage across the capacitor with that series resistance can't instantly change to 9V because the capacitor's charging current is limited to a maximum of 9/R mA.

So when the 9V step voltage is applied there is momentarily 9/R mA flowing in the resistor. So, the charging current for the capacitor is also 9/R mA (components in series must always have the same current through them). As time passes, the capacitor charges and the voltage across it increases. The input voltage is a fixed 9V and so the increasing voltage across the capacitor results in a reducing voltage across the resistor and so the capacitor's charging current (which is proportional to the rate at which the voltage across the capacitor is changing) must also reduce as time passes (i=VR/R). These changes happen in the classical exponential way as described by the classical exponential equations.

Eventually the voltage across the resistor drops to almost 0V, the voltage across the capacitor has risen to almost 9V and the capacitor is said to be fully charged. The circuit has passed it's transient phase and has reached it's stable, resting phase.

The capacitor's charging current doesn't actually flow through the capacitor. No conduction current can flow through a capacitor (apart from a tiny leakage current). The circuit's series (and one way current) can be explained by positive charge flowing on to the left hand side plate of the capacitor and positive charge being removed from the right hand plate leading to an increasing voltage between the plates.